# Bootstrap grid one full column and 2 stacked columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, are we able to do something like this? A full column first and two stacked columns beside it. I tried nested grid but it is not working.

[image: um]

Comment: where is your testing code?put it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this.i will explain this if the answer is correct

```
  <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 p-0">
         <div class="bg-dark">
            my life its always null..
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 p-0 ">
         <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-12 bg-primary ">
               THE Iternal Love 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 bg-primary ">
               THE Iternal Love 2
            </div>

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
             Content2
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">   
             Content3
           </div>
         </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```